# Async Delegate invocation and callback

Tags: c#, asynchronous, delegates

```
public delegate string AsyncMethodCaller(int callDuration, out int threadId);

class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        int threadId;

        AsyncMethodCaller caller = new AsyncMethodCaller(TestMethod);

        IAsyncResult result = caller.BeginInvoke(3000,
            out threadId, new AsyncCallback(Callback), null);

        Console.WriteLine("Main thread {0} does some work.",
            Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId);

        string returnValue = caller.EndInvoke(out threadId, result);

        Console.WriteLine("The call executed on thread {0}, with return value \"{1}\".",
            threadId, returnValue);
    }

    static public string TestMethod(int callDuration, out int threadId)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Test method begins.");
        Thread.Sleep(callDuration);
        threadId = Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId;
        return String.Format("My call time was {0}.", callDuration.ToString());
    }

    static void Callback(IAsyncResult result)
    {
        int a = 5;
        int b = 20;

        int c = a + b;

        Console.WriteLine(c + Environment.NewLine);
    }
}
```

This code basically executes TestMethod Asynchronously. But the problem I have is the after calling the EndInvoke on caller the main thread stops and waits for the TestMethod do complete the job. so basically the whole application is stuck. can this process be made asynchronous. ? I mean the thing I want is to invoke some method asynchronously and then wait for callback but if I remove EndInvoke call then CallBack is not hit. What is the best practice in this situation.

Comment: Your callback isn't being hit because the main thread has finished.  This isn't usually a problem in GUI applications because the UI thread is always running.  You should try adding a loop to simulate the main thread doing work.  That way it will still be alive when the callback gets called.

Comment: This looks like it is the exact example from [Calling Synchronous Methods Asynchronously](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2e08f6yc.aspx) where it says **Because EndInvoke might block, you should never call it from threads that service the user interface.**.  Later is shows __Executing a Callback Method When an Asynchronous Call Completes__.  However, why don't you use the `TPL`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You better use Tasks and their Task.Wait methods.
http://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/dd321424.aspx

smthing like this:

```
var returnValue = Task<string>.Factory.StartNew(() => TestMethod());
```

Comment: what about the callback ? I want callback to be hit when TestMethod hast finished executing.

Comment: @Dima
there is a stuff like that http://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/dd321474.aspx
try smthing like that:
`Task tsk = new Task(TestMethod);
Tasl tskCont = tsk.ContinueWith(Callback);`

Comment: anyway, seems like its all about TPL